# MIPS Code dependencies

Tags: mips

There is this exercise where you are suppose to identify the data dependencies in this MIPS code(all mechanisms of forwarding are activated,there is no branch prediction), and the teacher answer was this:

-Line 1 to Line 2 , register $6.

-Line 2 to Line 3, register $4.

-Line 4 to Line 5 and 6, register $5.

```
Loop: addi $6, $6, 4
        lw $4, 0($6)
       add $5, $5, $4
       rol $2, $5, 1
       bne $0, $5, Loop
        sw $5, 0($6)
Exit:
```

I fail to understand why there is no data dependency from line 3 to line 4. Isnt the rol dependent on the contents of $5 which have been changed in line 3?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both lines 4 and 5 depend on line 3 via register $5, which is what your teacher said but with every line 1 off; perhaps there was a comment line before the ROL, or someone miscounted.